# how to get a 0:00:00.002000 time in string form like 2microsecond

Tags: python, datetime

Hello guys i have program where i'm getting a total time taken by the program to complete the operation for that code is:

```
from datetime import datetime
startTime = datetime.now()
.........................
.........................
print("Total Time Taken to uploading file- " + format(datetime.now() - startTime))
```

output:0:00:00.002000 or 0:00:20.912000
How do i convert decimal to like 2 microsecond or it print like 20 second_912 microsecond...Is there any module define in python for it? please help

Comment: @KlausD. i have tried some way but its not working that's why asking here at least  tell me module which define for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datetime.now() - startTime` returns a [`timedelta` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects).

This object expose a [`total_seconds()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) method which output a `float`.

So you should be able to convert this delta to microseconds like:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

startTime = datetime.now()
time.sleep(0.01)

seconds = (datetime.now() - startTime).total_seconds()
print(seconds)
micro = seconds * 1000
print(micro)
```

Ouput:

```
0.010115 # seconds
10.115   # micro seconds
```

Comment: thnx for the please can you tell me why you are taking time.sleep(0.01) is it necessary  to take that?

Comment: It's not, it just make this script wait 0.01 second as example, you should remove it

Comment: is it possible to get the TotalTime which is in the formate of "0:00:00:93600" in 0 hr, 0min, 0 sec, 936 microsec or only show whatever is max time like in this we have only microsec so it will write like TotalTIme =936 micro sec or "0:00:20:93600" In this TotalTIme =20 sec is it possible to get like that  ?please help me